# Running A Spring Boot App (Embedded Tomcat) with SSL and Unencrypted Simultaneously

Tags: tomcat, ssl, spring-boot, tomcat8

Is there a way to run a Spring Boot application (runnable war) so that it listens on two ports - one with SSL and one without SSL. I am using an embedded Tomcat 8.

SSL is currently being configured using

```
@Bean
@Profile('tls')
EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer servletContainerCustomizer ()
throws Exception {

    new EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer () {
        @Override
        public void customize (ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {
            TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcat = (TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) container
            tomcat.addConnectorCustomizers (
                    new TomcatConnectorCustomizer () {
                        @Override
                        public void customize (Connector connector) {
                            connector.setPort     (Integer.parseInt (retrieveRequiredSpringProperty ('ssl.connection.port')))
                            connector.setSecure   (true)
                            connector.setScheme   ('https')
                            connector.setProtocol (retrieveSpringPropertyOrSpecified ('ssl.connection.protocol', 'HTTP/1.1'))

                            Http11NioProtocol proto = (Http11NioProtocol) connector.getProtocolHandler ()
                            proto.setSSLEnabled   (true)
                            proto.setKeystoreFile (retrieveRequiredSpringProperty ('ssl.protocol.keystore.file'))
                            proto.setKeystorePass (retrieveRequiredSpringProperty ('ssl.protocol.keystore.password'))
                            proto.setKeyPass      (retrieveSpringPropertyOrSpecified ('ssl.protocol.keystore.cert.password', null))
                            proto.setKeystoreType ('JKS')
                            proto.setKeyAlias     (retrieveRequiredSpringProperty ('ssl.protocol.keystore.cert.name'))
                            proto.setSslProtocol  ('TLS')
                            proto.setClientAuth   ('false')
                        }
                    }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried using multiple `TomcatConnectorCustomizer`s but the last one listed seems to overwrite rather than be additive.

Any suggestions are welcome as always!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `TomcatConnectorCustomizer` only modifies the existing `Connector` (clue in the name). To add additional connectors you just need a different API (example [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-tomcat-multi-connectors/src/main/java/sample/tomcat/SampleTomcatTwoConnectorsApplication.java)), e.g. (copied from the sample):

```
@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainer() {
    TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcat = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
    tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(createConnector());
    return tomcat;
}
```