# How set up Spring Boot to run HTTPS / HTTP ports

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ssl

Spring boot have some properties to config web port and SSL settings, but once a SSL certificate is set the http port turns into https port.

So, how can I keep both ports running on it, for example: 80 an 443 at the same time?

As you can see, there only properties for one port, in this case "server.ssl" is enabled, what makes http port be disabled automatically.

```
##############
### Server ###
##############
server.port=9043
server.session-timeout=1800
server.ssl.key-store=file:///C:/Temp/config/localhost.jks
server.ssl.key-store-password=localhost
server.ssl.key-password=localhost
server.ssl.trust-store=file:///C:/Temp/config/localhost.jks
server.ssl.trust-store-password=localhost
```

I am trying to use even Tomcat or Undertow. I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: Why do you want both running at the same time?  Either the line is secure or insecure, but it shouldn't be both.

Comment: Some parts of my project needs be secured, and another ones not. As you know Https traffic is slower than Http, so I'd like to interchange both protocols at the same time as we do in any application server.

Comment: @Makoto - not necessarily. one port can support both HTTP and HTTPS. for example - http://bayou.io/release/0.9/docs/http/Server_SSL_Configuration.html

Comment: @ElLordCode - I'm not familiar with Boot; so you are saying it can have only one port?

Comment: Well, that's what happens in Spring Boot when I enable SSL settings, if I try to navigate into Http port gives "Unknown Host" using same port number

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running A Spring Boot App (Embedded Tomcat) with SSL and Unencrypted Simultaneously](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26618377/running-a-spring-boot-app-embedded-tomcat-with-ssl-and-unencrypted-simultaneou)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Spring Boot configuration using properties, allows configuring only one connector. What you need is multiple connectors and for this, you have to write a Configuration class. Follow instructions in

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.3.RELEASE/reference/html/howto-embedded-servlet-containers.html

You can find a working example of configuring HTTPS through properties and then HTTP though EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer below

http://izeye.blogspot.com/2015/01/configure-http-and-https-in-spring-boot.html?showComment=1461632100718#c4988529876932015554

```
server:
  port: 8080
  ssl:
    enabled: true
    keyStoreType: PKCS12
    key-store: /path/to/keystore.p12
    key-store-password: password
  http:
    port: 8079
```

---

```
@Configuration
public class TomcatConfig {

@Value("${server.http.port}")
private int httpPort;

@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer containerCustomizer() {
    return new EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer() {
        @Override
        public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {
            if (container instanceof TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) {
                TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory containerFactory =
                        (TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) container;

                Connector connector = new Connector(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.DEFAULT_PROTOCOL);
                connector.setPort(httpPort);
                containerFactory.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(connector);
            }
        }
    };
}
}
```

Comment: and `server.http.port` does not seem to exist anymore.

Comment: @displayname server http port is a custom configuration defined by the programmer and not predefined in spring, in code you can see: @Value("${server.http.port}")
private int httpPort;

Comment: @user666 It used to exist afaik.

Comment: @Harish Gokavarapu and Adam Millerchip, how do this in command line? With an https springboot configuration, I tried this one: -Dserver.port=6010 -Dserver.http.port=6011, but only https port was changed not http port.

Comment: @displayname and user666, how do we set http.server.port then while mainting server.port for https?

Comment: This worked for me except I had to switch the port values. http.port should be your basic 8080 and server.port should be your desired https port, such as 8443

Answer (score 63):

The currently accepted answer works perfectly but needs some adaption if you want it to work with Spring Boot `2.0.0` and onwards:

```
@Component
public class HttpServer {
  @Bean
  public ServletWebServerFactory servletContainer(@Value("${server.http.port}") int httpPort) {
      Connector connector = new Connector(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.DEFAULT_PROTOCOL);
      connector.setPort(httpPort);

      TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcat = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory();
      tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(connector);
      return tomcat;
  }
}
```

---

or the ***Kotlin version***:

```
@Component
class HttpServer {
  @Bean
  fun servletContainer(@Value("\${server.http.port}") httpPort: Int): ServletWebServerFactory {
    val connector = Connector(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.DEFAULT_PROTOCOL)
    connector.setPort(httpPort)

    val tomcat = TomcatServletWebServerFactory()
    tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(connector)
    return tomcat
  }
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly on the newest version of spring boot.

Comment: This worked for me as well. Just wanted to clarify that this class REPLACES the TomcatConfig class in the accepted answer. Also my comment on the accepted answer about tweaking the yaml properties still applies.

Comment: Works fine for HTTP/HTTPS support tested with Spring Boot `2.4.3` version.

Comment: What is the import for Connector class?

Answer (score 9):

### Bellow is a simple example of how to enable both HTTP/HTTPS ports for undertow.

Spring Boot only lets to open one port by configuration. Second port has to be opened programmatically.

#### Open HTTP port first programmatically.

```
import org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.undertow.UndertowServletWebServerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerFactoryCustomizer;

@Configuration
public class UndertowConfig {

@Value("${server.http.port}")
private int httpPort;

@Value("${server.http.interface}")
private String httpInterface;

@Bean
public WebServerFactoryCustomizer<UndertowServletWebServerFactory> containerCustomizer() {
    return (WebServerFactoryCustomizer) factory -> {
        UndertowServletWebServerFactory undertowFactory = (UndertowServletWebServerFactory) factory;
        undertowFactory.getBuilderCustomizers().add(builder -> {
            builder.addHttpListener(httpPort, httpInterface);
        });
    };
}
```

}

## HTTPS by configuration

Spring can open one either HTTP or HTTPS port reading properties from an available property source. If you add appropriate configuration as shown bellow it would be good enough to have HTTPs port open.

```
#default secured port (Spring will open it automatically)
server.port=8443
#additional HTTP port (will open it in UndertowConfig)
server.http.port=8080
#Open to the world
server.http.interface=0.0.0.0
#These settings tell Spring to open SSL port
server.ssl.keystore=file:${APP_BASE}/conf/server/ssl_selfsigned/server.keystore
server.ssl.key-store-password=xyz
server.ssl.key-password=xyz
```

#### HTTPS by manual setup

You can open another SSL port the same way as you opened HTTP port if you want by doing this

```
 .addHttpsListener(ssl_port, httpInterface, getSSLContext());
```

This is how you can create SSL context

```
import javax.net.ssl.*;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.security.KeyStore;

public SSLContext getSSLContext() throws Exception
{
    return createSSLContext(loadKeyStore(serverKeystore,keyStorePassword),
            loadKeyStore(serverTruststore,trustStorePassword));

}


private SSLContext createSSLContext(final KeyStore keyStore,
                                    final KeyStore trustStore) throws Exception {

    KeyManager[] keyManagers;
    KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, keyStorePassword.toCharArray());
    keyManagers = keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers();

    TrustManager[] trustManagers;
    TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    trustManagerFactory.init(trustStore);
    trustManagers = trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers();

    SSLContext sslContext;
    sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    sslContext.init(keyManagers, trustManagers, null);

    return sslContext;
}


private static KeyStore loadKeyStore(final String storeLoc, final String storePw) throws Exception {
    InputStream stream = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get(storeLoc));
    if(stream == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Could not load keystore");
    }
    try(InputStream is = stream) {
        KeyStore loadedKeystore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        loadedKeystore.load(is, storePw.toCharArray());
        return loadedKeystore;
    }
}
```

Comment: This solutions works perfectly with undertow, thanks

Comment: can you please add some codes on the above implementation for HTTP 2.0

Comment: In my case the `@Value` injection didn't work that easily because my configuration was more complex. I explained my situation and what ended up working for me in [this GitHub issue comment](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2191#issuecomment-994600592).

Answer (score 5):

Another Spring boot 2.x solution:

```
private static final int HTTP_PORT = 80;
private static final int HTTPS_PORT = 443;
private static final String HTTP = "http";
private static final String USER_CONSTRAINT = "CONFIDENTIAL";

@Bean
public ServletWebServerFactory servletContainer() {
    TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcat = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory() {
        @Override
        protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
            SecurityConstraint securityConstraint = new SecurityConstraint();
            securityConstraint.setUserConstraint(USER_CONSTRAINT);
            SecurityCollection collection = new SecurityCollection();
            collection.addPattern("/*");
            securityConstraint.addCollection(collection);
            context.addConstraint(securityConstraint);
        }
    };
    tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(redirectConnector());
    return tomcat;
}

private Connector redirectConnector() {
    Connector connector = new Connector(
            TomcatServletWebServerFactory.DEFAULT_PROTOCOL);
    connector.setScheme(HTTP);
    connector.setPort(HTTP_PORT);
    connector.setSecure(false);
    connector.setRedirectPort(HTTPS_PORT);
    return connector;
}
```

And set in your properties **server.port=443**

Comment: What is the import for `Context`?

Comment: @MJBZA Import for Context is org.apache.catalina

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at: https://github.com/creactiviti/spring-boot-starter-acme. It makes it very easy to auto-generate a LetsEncrypt based SSL certificate.

From the README:

1. Add the module to your pom.xml file as a dependency.
2. Build your project.
3. Deploy it to a target machine and point your domain name to the IP address of that machine. LetsEncrypt validates your ownership of the domain by making a callback to the http://your-domain/.well-known/acme-challenge/{token} endpoint exposed by this module.
4. Make sure that your server has openssl available on its $PATH.
5. To activate spring-boot-starter-acme and generate a certificate execute:

   `sudo java -Dserver.port=80 -Dacme.enabled=true -Dacme.domain-name=<YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME> -Dacme.accept-terms-of-service=true -jar mysecureapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`
6. Check your console for a confirmation that the certificate was successfully generated.
7. Stop your application and configure it to make use of the generated certificate:

   `server.port=443
   server.ssl.key-store=keystore.p12
   server.ssl.key-store-password=password
   server.ssl.keyStoreType=PKCS12`

Comment: Idealy, and what broght me here, is if the webapp can renew certificate automatically while running. For this to work I have to expose the  */.well-known/acme-challenge endpoint in http which is a problem since the rest of my webapp runs on https.

Answer (score 0):

The top answers are all great and probably work but I've been using Undertow with JHipster so they didn't work for me (and this was the main [search](https://www.ecosia.org/) result). The right code for Undertow is mentioned in [this issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2191) specifically:

```
@Bean
public UndertowServletWebServerFactory embeddedServletContainerFactory() {
    UndertowServletWebServerFactory factory = new UndertowServletWebServerFactory();
    factory.addBuilderCustomizers(new UndertowBuilderCustomizer() {
        @Override
        public void customize(Undertow.Builder builder) {
            builder.addHttpListener(8080, "0.0.0.0");
        }
    });
    return factory;
}
```

Comment: Try to avoid answering questions with [an answer already present there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49740689/5043355).