# Java Springboot on HTTPS: how to change default http port 8080 to another value

Tags: java, spring-boot, http, tomcat, https

Hi Java and Springboot Gurus,

This regarding a project I have created in Java using springboot.
I was able to successfully create and setup an https project in spring boot.
Then to set the HTTPS port I have just to set via commandline instead in application.properties via this command in the terminal:

```
$ java -Dserver.port=6001 -jar myapp-0.0.1.jar
```

I made it like this so that I can easily create other instances that will be running in other ports let say 6002, 6003 and so on...

But the problem is that, there is this default HTTP Port that tomcat sets:

```
2019-08-16 02:42:36.768  INFO 6 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 6001 (https) 8080 (http)
```

I want to get rid of this or perhaps assign it to another port e.g. 6081.
I have read this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30896234/how-set-up-spring-boot-to-run-https-http-ports), and its setting it up programmatically. 
But I want to avoid that.
I just want it to be something I can add as parameter in the command line like -Dserver.port=6001. To avoid further complicating my project as much as I can. 
I tried doing this:

```
$ java -Dserver.port=6001 -Dserver.http.port=6081 -jar myapp-0.0.1.jar
```

... but it doesn't work.
Your ideas and inputs will be much appreciated!

Comment: server.http.port is not supported anymore.  Do you have tls/ssl configured?

Comment: @ChrisMaggiulli... yes, in fact it is a working https server already.

Comment: I didn't read your entire post as first.  If you aren't using properties you need to use Java Config. Do you want to seta ngix server or httpd server on 80 that forwards https requests to Spring through AJP. Or do you want to expose your spring boot server directly over https without a web server ?

Comment: @ChrisMaggiulli, all good. This is actually a Web Server encapsulating an Angular Front End. Which means, it won't be interacting with any server in front of it. This will be the Front End web server. We are just using the http endpoint and completely ignoring the http:8080. I am accessing this webserver already like "https://myapp:443". I can live with ignoring http:8080 but the problem is that everytime I spawn another instance, it also have an http port 8080. If I can get rid of the http port per instance or at least set each http port number uniquely. Like 6081, 6082, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting server.port=-1 in your application.properties. See [Spring Boot doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-change-the-http-port).

[Update]

You may redirect your HTTP to HTTPS.

To achieve this you need another connector. SpringBoot does not allow to configure multiple connector with application.properties. So we can write a connector programmatically. Connector example for Tomcat:

```
@Configuration
public class MyTomcatConnector {

    @Bean
    public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainer() {
        TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcat = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory() {
            @Override
            protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
                SecurityConstraint securityConstraint = new SecurityConstraint();
                securityConstraint.setUserConstraint("CONFIDENTIAL");
                SecurityCollection collection = new SecurityCollection();
                collection.addPattern("/*");
                securityConstraint.addCollection(collection);
                context.addConstraint(securityConstraint);
            }
        };  
        tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(initiateHttpConnector());
        return tomcat;
    }  
    private Connector initiateHttpConnector() {
        Connector connector = new Connector("org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol");
        connector.setScheme("http");
        connector.setPort(8080);
        connector.setSecure(false);
        connector.setRedirectPort(6001);
        return connector;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure about this, but with that parameter... that's where I have set my https port. "$java -Dserver.port=6001 -jar myapp-0.0.1.jar", is already running on https. I'm afraid if I do that, it will either shut off my https port or my https port would be something of unknown arbitrary value. But most importantly, given your solution? How do I set now my https port?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your problem earlier. I have updated my answer now. Check if that works.

Comment: all good. yes, I have came across that one after I have posted my question here. I think I have no choice but to programmatically set the ports.