# How to open port 80 (HTTP) and 433 (HTTPS) in Java spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, http, https, port

I want to open port 80 for http and port 433 for https. The port 80 should be redirected to 433. I set the server port in `application.properties` to port 80:

```
server.port=80
```

And to redirect I followed the official spring documentation and created this small class:

```
public class HTTPSRedirector {

    @Bean
    SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        http.redirectToHttps();
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

But now the server times out and when I try using curl with the following command:

curl -v http://www.example.com/

I get a `Bad request` response because SSL/TLS is enabled. If I try to ping / contact the https port like this:

curl -v https://www.example.com/

then I get the message that the port is not opened and the connection was refused. How can I open both ports 80 and 433 in my Java spring project?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30896234/how-set-up-spring-boot-to-run-https-http-ports

Also, make sure you test locally first.
If you´re actually testing with an FQDN which is even routed outside of your network then make sure the traffic get´s forwarded to your springboot application by the firewall/router.

If you´re running the springboot application locally then try to telnet onto port 443 and see if it´s opened (I think it´s not since you only enabled port 80 but you have no connector for 443 in the code you´ve shown)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way how I finally fixed it:

I used the bean listed in my question. This bean redirects all http requests to https.

ADDITIONALLY to that I set the server port to:

```
server.port=443
```

which is the default port for `https`. With these two changes the server works fine and everything is https.