# How to stop https redirect with spring boot 1.3

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a project with older spring-boot version(1.3.1) and I need to run the server on both http and https but **I do not want the redirect from http to https**. But the way I have setup the additonal tomcat connector to start on http also is actually redirecting it to https, I do not know how to stop this redirection.
For Https I have added the ssl properties.

```
server.ssl.key-store-type:PKCS12
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:<pk12 file>
server.ssl.key-store-password:<password>
server.ssl.key-alias:<alias>
server.port=8443

#HTTP port
http.port=8080
```

For Http I have created below bean

```
@Value("${http.port}")
private int httpPort;

@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer customizeTomcatConnector() {

    return new EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer() {

        @Override
        public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {

            if (container instanceof TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) {
                TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory containerFactory =
                (TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) container;
                Connector connector = new Connector(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.DEFAULT_PROTOCOL);
                connector.setPort(httpPort);
                containerFactory.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(connector);\
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Could someone kindly suggest how can I stop forceHttps redirect.

**Edit**
My server starts on both http and https fine but I am trying to stop the redirect from http to https which happens whenever I am trying to access the api with http

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How set up Spring Boot to run HTTPS / HTTP ports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30896234/how-set-up-spring-boot-to-run-https-http-ports)

Comment: I am already able to run the server on http and https but somehow a redirect is happening from http to https, I need to stop that but not sure I can do that.