# Bare minimum configurations required to hit URL with HTTPS from local (REST to SOAP)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ssl

So I have been recently going through few articles on enabling SSL in spring boot on local machine

**For e.g.** [How set up Spring Boot to run HTTPS / HTTP ports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30896234/how-set-up-spring-boot-to-run-https-http-ports)

Let's say my Spring boot application YML has following defined (Few other definitions too)

```
someService(SOAP Based):

  username: someUserName

  uri: https://qa01-some-service-war.appcloud-np.barclays.intranet/someservice/v1/someservice.wsdl

  password:
```

*My Question is what is the bare minimum I require if at runtime I want to call this "some-service" , assuming everything else is properly defined!*

***Just to add up more, I am facing this exception as of now  (Which wouldn't I think if I pass the password field correctly)***

`org.springframework.ws.soap.client.SoapFaultClientException: The security token could not be authenticated or authorized; nested exception is org.apache.wss4j.common.ext.WSSecurityException: The security token could not be authenticated or authorized`

Answer (score 0):

Hope this one helps, These are basic steps one must follow to setup ssl for springboot.

https://www.thomasvitale.com/https-spring-boot-ssl-certificate/

Add these configurations

```
server:
  ssl:
    key-store: classpath:keystore.p12
    key-store-password: password
    key-store-type: pkcs12
    key-alias: springboot
    key-password: password
  port: 8443
```

Comment: I checked out this too ! Sorry didn't mention :P Any other solution if Spring boot (REST based) is calling a SOAP service ?

Comment: It does not matter what you are calling, you must check for firewall on your system if you are facing problems while invoking an https or http service. Above article is to setup your API invokes using https.